# Why is PHPMailer class not included in file?

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer, filepath

I have written some code to send email. Now i have multiple scripts that uses PHPMailer to send emails. So what i did was i wrote all my SMTP settings in a file after including PHPMailerAutoLoad.php but it still is throwing an error 'Class PHPMailer not found.'

Following is the code snippet of mailsetting.ph which has settings regarding my SMTP Server.

```
<?php
include("/../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail= new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                          
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                         
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     
$mail->Username = 'username';                    
$mail->Password = 'password';                                  
$mail->Port =465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->From='info@vishalkhare.com';
$mail->FromName='Vishal Khare';
$mail->addReplyTo('info@vishalkhare.com', 'Information');
?>
```

It says 'Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in mailsetting.php on line 3' which clearly means that include statement is executing properly. But Still Class PHPMailer is not included.
I also tried including the class.phpmailer.php file

```
<?php
include("../class.phpmailer.php");
include("../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
?>
```

It is still not working. Please help me out and let me know what to do to include PHPMailer class in the file?

P.S. - It is working on a XAMPP Server but not working as i move the code to a webserver. A godaddy Web server precisely

Comment: I believe line 3 needs to be changed to: `$mail= new PHPMailer();`

Comment: @Tex Ya i understand. But it is still not working

Comment: What error do you see after changing line 3 to `$mail= new PHPMailer();`?

Comment: Change line 2 to `require("/../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");` and tell us what result you get.

Comment: @Tex Same error. See it is working on a XAMPP server. So do you think it has something to do with godaddy's server on which it is? Like some dependencies which are missing or something like that?

Comment: @Tex: no, `new PHPMailer()` and `new PHPMailer` are treated the same.

Comment: It's well known (it's in the PHPMailer documentation and many questions on SO) that **GoDaddy blocks outbound SMTP**, so even if you fix your paths you will have trouble connecting. In the mean time, use `require` instead of `include` and get your paths right - there's no point in continuing if the load fails.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in loading PHPMailAutoLad. Unfortunately Godaddy doesn't support emails of gmail,yahoo,aol,live,hotmail,etc., IF you are using linux cPanel hosting panel then make these changes in your php files

```
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Port = 25;  
$mail->ssl = false;
$mail->authentication = false;
```